# ASP.Net ImageButton stealing Enter key press

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, webforms

I have an ASP.Net page with a usercontrol on it. The submit button for the page is within the usercontrol. There is an ImageButton on the page itself (outside of the usercontrol). Whenever I hit the enter key to submit the form, it always executes the ImageButton click instead of the submit button within the usercontrol.

I'm using a MasterPage for the style, so the form is within that which rules out using the form's DefaultButton property.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put your controls inside a panel and set that panel's [`DefaultButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx) property.

Comment: Not that it affects this exact situation, but always needs clarification that the `DefaultButton` property doesn't work for the `LinkButton` control (in browsers other than IE).

Answer (score 1):

Add focus on page load.

This example might help: http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/1611.htm

It sets the focus on submit button, but focus will be lost when you click a text field in the form.

Comment: +1 - might not be what Aaron was looking for but useful nonetheless.